# change specific value in mdf-object (python, asammdf)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-consistency, asammdf

I would like to change some values in an mdf file (specifically, I would like to check for consistency, since the measurement instrument for some reason writes `10**10` when no value could be found). I can't figure out how to access specific values and change them. I figured out how to include the channel units in the channel names, which works reasonably fast:

```
with MDF(file) as mdf:
    for i,gp in enumerate(mdf.groups):# add units to channel names (faster than using pandas)
        for j,ch in enumerate(gp.channels):
            mdf.groups[i].channels[j].name = ch.name + " [" + ch.unit + "]"
```

Unfortunately, `gp.channels` doesn't seem to have a way to access the data, only some metadata for each channel (or at least I can't figure out the attribute or method).

I already tried to convert to a dataframe, where this is rather easy, but the file is quite large so it takes waaaay too long to sift through all the datapoints - my guess is this could be quite a bit faster if it is done in the mdf directly.

```
# slow method with dataframe conversion
data = mdf.to_dataframe()
columns = data.columns.tolist()
for col in columns:
    for i,val in enumerate(data[col]):
        if val == 10**10:
            data.loc[i, col] = np.nan
```

Downsampling solves the taking too long part, but this is not really a solution either since I do need the original sample rate.
Accessing the data is not a problem, since I can use the `select()` or `get()` methods, but I can't change the values - I don't know how. Ideally, I'd change any `10**10` to a `np.nan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured out how to do if efficiently in `pandas`, which works for me.
I used an combination of a `lambda` function and the `applymap` method of a `pandas DataFrame`:

```
data = data.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x==10**10 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you still get the 10**10 values when you call get with ignore_invalidation_bots=False? In mdf v4 the writing applications can use the invalidation bits to mark invalid samples